# Can't resolve getProofOfPayment Paypal

Tags: android, methods, paypal

I'm a newbie in coding. I am trying to add Paypal Payments to my app and found a tutorialvideo for that but in I get an error:

`getProofOfPayment` method can't be resolved.

Do you have any idea why? I did everything like in the tutorial so far and there was no error.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView m_response;

    PayPalConfiguration m_configuration;

    String m_paypalClientid;

    Intent m_service;

    int m_paypalRequestCode = 999;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

        m_configuration = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
        .clientId(m_paypalClientid);

        m_service = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        m_service.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);
        startService(m_service);
    }

    void pay (View view){
        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(10), "EUR", "Tes payment for Paypal",
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalPayment.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, m_configuration);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, m_paypalRequestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == m_paypalRequestCode)

        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                PayPalConfiguration confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

                if (confirmation != null)
                {
                    String state = confirmation.getProofOfPayment().getState();

                    if (state.equals("approved"))
                        m_response.setText("Payment approved");
                    else
                        m_response.setText("Error in the payment");

                }
                else
                    m_response.setText("confirmation is null");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an object of Type `PaymentConfirmation` instead of your `PayPalConfiguration` in Method `onActivityResult`

Just replace it and it should work.

Comment: OMG!!! such a stupid mistake... and I suppose to follow the tutorial hehe thank you very much!! all works!

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting the answer then.